# Secure communication for MSMQ

Tags: c#, security, authentication, msmq

I have created a Private MSMQ and I am able to send messages to it. What I am now looking to do is to only allow a single user access to the queue and then send messages to that queue using that users credentials.

I am thinking about impersonating the user (I have an impersonator class) before sending the message but not sure how to do this.

any ideas on whats the best way to do this.

Oh! I am using C#.

Comment: Use standard Windows security.  Right-click the queue, Properties, Security tab.  "Send" and "Receive" permission can be assigned per user account.  Impersonating doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What user will be running the executable? You can simply give that user access to the queue, and avoid impersonation altogether.

Impersonation is usually useful when you try to run different pieces of code as *several* different users. If you don't need several users, don't bother with impersonating at all.

Comment: So say I have 2 users, one who can send messages to the queue and one who can both send and receive. Is it easy as giving these 2 users and only these 2 users those permissions?

Comment: It should be, you just set the proper permissions on the queue.

Comment: Important note if you really want to secure the queue. MSMQ just sends the SID of the user account in a message which can easily be spoofed by anyone with access to the network. Use authentication/certificates instead if you can.